# Unexpected behavior with switch statements on LLVM 3.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, llvm

I have recently switched to LLVM 3.0 compiler from LLVM GCC 4.2 when compiling iOS apps. Everything seem to work the same, except some of my switch statements. It looks like something is wrong when Obj-C methods are directly used inside switch condition.

I have created the main.m file below to reproduce this. It is printing `property: 846` whereas it should clearly print `property: 2`. Is there anything wrong with my usage of switch or could this be a bug in the compiler?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface STSomeClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation STSomeClass

- (int)mytype{
  return 2;
}

- (int)someProperty{
  switch ([self mytype]) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3: 
    case 6: 
    case 8:
    case 9:
        return 2;
    case 4:
    case 7:
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
  }
}

- (void)printSomeProperty{
  printf("property: %d\n", [self someProperty]);
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  STSomeClass* someObject;

  someObject = [[STSomeClass alloc] init];
  [someObject printSomeProperty];
  [someObject release];
}
```

**UPDATE**:

To make it clear how I compile the code:

- I am using Xcode 4.2 and iOS SDK 5.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Using LLVM 3.0
- Compiling the code with -Os (also tried -O1)
- Building for arvm7 and testing on iPad with iOS 4.2.1 (also tried iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0)

Comment: use breaks It might be the fact that you change the my type value, if you change the value inside a casewhitout break it will check the other case.

Comment: @Radu: `return`s in switch blocks are perfectly legal. Not sure what you're on about changing the type.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this code two ways: Xcode 4.4, llvm 4.0, ARC and Xcode 4.3, llvm 3,1 no-ARC both with OS X 10.7.3, iOS 4.3 target and iOS 5.0. simulator and got "property: 2" both times.

So, there is something else going on in your case. What exact configuration are you using?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention it. I am testing it on an iPad (also tested on an iPhone 4) and compiling with -Os flag.

Comment: It looks like I cannot download Xcode 4.4 and test with llvm 4.0. Is it only accessible to Mac Developers?

Comment: I tried -Os, on an iPad2 running iSO 5.0.1 still got the correct result. The lack of an autorelease pool does concern me though.

Comment: Thanks for trying. That seems quite close to my configuration. I wonder why I see different results. I have removed @autoreleasepool block just to test it with LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler. Adding it did not make any difference.

Comment: Where the heck are you getting an LLVM 4.0 from when 3.1 is still in development and the latest is 3.0?